# React Material UI - DataGrid Keeps Stealing Focus from Input Field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, material-ui

I'm creating a React web application with Material-UI, and I'm running into a problem where my Material-UI DataGrid always steals the browser focus away from my search input field as I try to type in it. This problem does not occur right when I load the page. It only happens when I first click somewhere on the table to focus on it, and then click on the search bar and try to type something. Right as I type the first letter and the state of my page is updated, the focus goes to a cell on my table so I can no longer type in my search box without clicking on it again (and then the process repeats for each letter I type).

From my research, a lot of people have run into this issue because they are not putting proper keys on their React elements, so they lose focus on their input field whenever the state of the page changes. However, I've made sure to include keys on all elements that have sibling elements, which should take care of that from my understanding. I have also included the line: onKeyDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} in my InputBase field because I read on another Stack Overflow post that sometimes the DataGrid can intercept KeyDown events, but that didn't help either.

[Snippet to make the issue clearer (zoomed in on top left of table + search bar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnXQ8.png)

Here is all the JavaScript code that encompasses my problem:

```
<Paper key="paperGrid">
    <Grid key="contentGrid" container style={{paddingTop: 4, paddingBottom: 8}}>
        <Grid key="searchGrid" item xs={4}>
            <Paper key="searchPaper" component="form" className={classes.root}>
                <InputBase
                    key="searchInput"
                    className={classes.input}
                    placeholder="Search Job Configs..."
                    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Search Job Configs' }}
                    onChange={searchJobs}
                    onKeyDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
                />
                <IconButton key="searchButton" className={classes.iconButton} aria-label="search">
                    <SearchIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid key="testing" item xs={2}>
            <h3>Testing</h3>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <div key="dataGrid" style={{ height: '40vw', width: '80vw' }}>
        <DataGrid
            key="jobConfigsTable"
            rows={filterJobList} 
            columns={jobColumns} 
            pageSize={25} 
            rowsPerPageOptions={[25, 50, 100]}
            getRowId={(row) => row.psrunId}
            checkboxSelection 
        />
    </div>
</Paper>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out something that works? I have the same problem and the state answer below isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem. When the component rerendered, it would take focus back to the last clicked cell.

Using the `state` prop in DataGrid, I was able to fix this for my use case, but note this might have unintended consequences for you.

```
<DataGrid
  state={{
    keyboard: {
      cell: null,
      columnHeader: null,
      isMultipleKeyPressed: false,
    }
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onSubmit` rather than `onChange` in your `<inputBase />` like so:

```
<InputBase
    key="searchInput"
    className={classes.input}
    placeholder="Search Job Configs..."
    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Search Job Configs' }}
    onSubmit={searchJobs}
    onKeyDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
/>
```

`onChange` triggers `searchJobs` every time your input changes. Changing it to `onSubmit` should trigger your search as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I gave that a shot but onSubmit reloads the page which isn't quite what I'm going for. I actually would like the table rows to be filtered as the user is typing. That isn't possible with onSubmit, correct?

Comment: I believe this has to do with datagrid focusing when re-rendering after the jobs change. Unfortunately I also have this problem, and do not see a solution online.